# Download file in AWS S3 bucket using SSIS

Tags: amazon-s3, ssis, business-intelligence

Is there a way to download a file from AWS S3 source to local using SSIS?

I have files in different formats like json, csv that are sitting in ASW S3 and I would like to load the data in SQL Server On Prem using SSIS. The files comes in different names daily, the method should also enable me to pass variables of the file name and file path that needs to be downloaded. Can I achieve this without using any third party tools that need payment?